# how can i make text appear without clicking anything in HTML or JS?

Tags: javascript

I don't need help with getting text on my page in HTML, i know how to do that. You know how like in MS-DOS when loading stuff text appears like:

*Starting MS-DOS...
MODE select code page function complete.*

i've thought about calling a StartTimer and making it change the opacity of the div instantly but i'm not sure if that will work, i've been trying to find anything similar to my question online but there isn't anything. thanks if you help.

Comment: without js will be difficult

Comment: use css and do animation

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Use `setTimeout()` to run code after a time delay.

Answer (score 0):

Your title indicates that you don't want to "click anything... [in] JS", so I assume that means that you're still ok with using JavaScript altogether given that you mention calling a function in your question body. Presumably you just want it to work immediately when the page loads as opposed to someone "clicking something".

If you just want to make it appear after some time use:

Your HTML markup:

```
<div id="myDiv" style="opacity:0">Starting MS-DOS</div>
```

And your JS:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  document.querySelector("myDiv").style.opacity = 1;}
, 3000);
```

This will display the text to the page after 3 seconds immediately. You could also fade it into the screen with something like:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    document.querySelector("div#myDiv").style.opacity += 0.1;
    if (document.querySelector("div#myDiv").style.opacity >= 1) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 250);
}, 1000);
```

This approach would wait 1 second, then fade in the text over 2.5 seconds via the setInterval before clearing that interval upon hitting an opacity of 1.

Answer (score 0):

**How about this one, I have created this with only css**

```css
body {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

@keyframes anim {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.start {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: anim 1.5s;
}

.end {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: anim 1s 1.5s forwards;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="start">Starting MS-DOS...</h2>
<h2 class="end">C:\></h2>
```